# Make a ramp up a lowpoly hill

Tags: modeling

I have a very simple mesh that is completely flat, but the edges are cut out with a knife tool. How can I make a ramp up this hill? Everything I try turns bad.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want your ramp to be "inside" the hill instead of without, it requires a few more steps, but uses the same principles as outlined by JACHYM MICHAL.

**Method 1:**

[image]

- Start by deleting the n-gon that comprises the top of the hill.
- Select the faces you wish to comprise your ramp, and hit <kbd>E</kbd> to extrude them.
- In vertex select mode, hit <kbd>X</kbd> and delete unwanted geometry.
- In edge select mode, select the two edges as shown, and tap <kbd>G</kbd> +  <kbd>G</kbd> to edge slide them into place.
- Select everything with <kbd>A</kbd>, and hit <kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>M</kbd> > By Distance to removed doubled vertices.
- Still in edge select mode, hold down <kbd>ALT</kbd> and click and edge to select the loop of edges around the top, and press <kbd>F</kbd> to fill.

**Method 2:**

[image]

- Start again by deleting the top face.
- This time, select only the edges that will be the top of your ramp.
- Press <kbd>V</kbd> to rip these edges and <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> + <kbd>Z</kbd> to constrain movement to the X-Y plane. Move the edges into place.
- Select edges and fill in faces as needed.
- You can continue to adjust your ramp by selecting the top edges and moving them with <kbd>G</kbd> and <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> + <kbd>Z</kbd>.

Comment: Better than my way :)

Answer (score 2):

If I understand correctly, you can use *Extrude Region* and *Edge slide* for that.

[image]

And an inside ramp
[image]

Comment: You beat me to it! I'll just add that you could slide the edge all the way in, then select everything with Alt + M > By Distance.

Comment: This is great and will definently do :) I was hoping that the ramp would stay "inside" the hill, if that makes sense? Any chance u could add an alternative for that? Or is that what @Rekov is talking about?